# Producer–consumer pattern deisgn issue

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, producer-consumer

I'm working on implements a tree that represent electric circus (without any circles, as in this picture)

[image: i.e.]

I use this implementation:

Binary_Oprtator

```
public abstract class Binary_Oprtator {
        abstract int calc(int x, int y);

        @Override
        public String toString() {
        return super.toString().substring(0, super.toString().indexOf('@'));
        }
}
```

And gate

```
public class and extends Binary_Oprtator {
        public int calc(int x, int y){
            return (x&y);
        }
}
```

Or gate

```
public class or extends Binary_Oprtator {
        public int calc(int x, int y){
            return (x|y);
        }
}
```

gate_node

```
public class gate_node {
    gate_node father_c;
    gate_node right_c, left_c;
    Binary_Oprtator op;
    int value;
    int right_v, left_v;
    int array_index;
    int arr_size;
    boolean leaf;
    boolean isRightChild;

    public gate_node(Binary_Oprtator op, int array_index, int arr_size, boolean right) {
        this.array_index = array_index;
        this.arr_size = arr_size;
        this.left_c = null;
        this.right_c = null;
        this.op = op;
        right_v = left_v = -1;
        this.leaf = false;
        this.isRightChild = right;

    }

    void set_left_son(Binary_Oprtator op) {
        this.left_c = new gate_node(op, array_index, arr_size / 2,false);
        this.left_c.father_c = this;
        this.left_c.leaf = false;
        this.left_c.isRightChild = false;
    }

    void set_right_son(Binary_Oprtator op) {
        this.right_c = new gate_node(op, array_index + arr_size / 2,
                arr_size / 2,true);
        this.right_c.father_c = this;
        this.right_c.leaf = false;
        this.right_c.isRightChild = true;
    }

    void set_left_son_as_leaf(Binary_Oprtator op) throws InterruptedException {
        this.left_c = new gate_node(op, array_index, arr_size / 2,false);
        this.left_c.father_c = this;
        this.left_c.leaf = true;
        this.left_c.left_v = main_class.arr[array_index];
        this.left_c.right_v = main_class.arr[array_index + 1];
        this.left_c.isRightChild = false;

        main_class.queue.put(this.left_c);
    }

    void set_right_son_as_leaf(Binary_Oprtator op) throws InterruptedException {
        this.right_c = new gate_node(op, array_index + arr_size / 2,
                arr_size / 2,true);
        this.right_c.father_c = this;
        this.right_c.left_v = main_class.arr[array_index + 2];
        this.right_c.right_v = main_class.arr[array_index + 3];
        this.right_c.leaf = true;
        this.right_c.isRightChild = true;

        main_class.queue.put(this.right_c);
    }

    gate_node get_left() {
        return this.left_c;
    }

    gate_node get_right() {
        return this.right_c;
    }

    int compute() {
        /*
         * The following use of a static sInputCounter assumes that the
         * static/global input array is ordered from left to right, irrespective
         * of "depth".
         */
        final int left, right;
        if (this.left_c.leaf != true) {
            left = this.left_c.compute();
        } else {
            left = this.left_c.op.calc(this.left_c.left_v, this.left_c.right_v);
        }
        if (this.right_c.leaf != true) {
            right = this.right_c.compute();

        } else {
            right = this.right_c.op.calc(this.right_c.left_v,
                    this.right_c.right_v);
        }

        return op.calc(left, right);
    }

    int compute_with_print() {
        /*
         * The following use of a static sInputCounter assumes that the
         * static/global input array is ordered from left to right, irrespective
         * of "depth".
         */

        final int left, right;
        System.out.print(this.op + "(");

        if (null != this.left_c) {
            left = this.left_c.compute_with_print();
            System.out.print(",");
        } else {
            left = main_class.arr[array_index];
            System.out.print(left + ",");
        }

        if (null != this.right_c) {
            right = this.right_c.compute_with_print();
            System.out.print(")");
        } else {
            right = main_class.arr[array_index + 1];

            System.out.print(right + ")");
        }

        return op.calc(left, right);
    }

}
```

tree

```
public class tree  {
    gate_node head;

    public tree(Binary_Oprtator op,int array_index,int arr_size) {
        this.head  = new gate_node(op,array_index,arr_size,true);
        head.father_c=null;

    }
    void calc_head_value(){
        int t_value = head.op.calc(head.left_v,head.right_v);
    /*  System.out.println(head.left_v+" "+head.op.toString()+" "+head.right_v+" = "+head.op.calc(head.left_v,head.right_v));
*/      head.value = t_value;
    }
    int compute() {
        return head.compute();
    }
    int compute_with_print(){
        return head.compute_with_print();
    }



    void set_left_son(Binary_Oprtator op){
        head.left_c = new gate_node(op,head.array_index,head.arr_size/2,false);
        head.left_c.father_c=head;

    }

    void set_right_son(Binary_Oprtator op){
        head.right_c = new gate_node(op,head.array_index + head.arr_size/2,head.arr_size/2,true);
        head.right_c.father_c=head;

    }

    void set_right_son_as_leaf(Binary_Oprtator op) throws InterruptedException {
        head.right_c = new gate_node(op,head.array_index,head.arr_size/2,false);
        head.right_c.father_c=head;
        head.right_c.father_c = head;
        head.right_c.left_v = main_class.arr[head.array_index + 2];
        head.right_c.right_v = main_class.arr[head.array_index + 3];
        head.right_c.leaf = true;
        head.right_c.isRightChild = true;

        main_class.queue.put(head.right_c);
    }

    void set_left_son_as_leaf(Binary_Oprtator op) throws InterruptedException {
        head.left_c = new gate_node(op, head.array_index, head.arr_size / 2,false);
        head.left_c.father_c = head;
        head.left_c.leaf = true;
        head.left_c.left_v = main_class.arr[head.array_index];
        head.left_c.right_v = main_class.arr[head.array_index + 1];
        head.left_c.isRightChild = false;

        main_class.queue.put(head.left_c);
    }

    gate_node get_left(){
        return head.left_c;
    }

    gate_node get_right(){
        return head.right_c;
    }

}
```

main_class

```
   import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class main_class {
    public static int arr[] = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 };

    static final BlockingQueue<gate_node> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(6);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

/*************************************
 * compute using multi threads
 ************************************/
        System.out.println("compute using Multi threading");

        //start a consumer... wait for nodes to be insert into the queue
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer();
        consumer.start();


        tree t = new tree(new and(), 0, arr.length);
        t.set_left_son(new or());
        t.get_left().set_left_son_as_leaf(new and());
        t.get_left().set_right_son_as_leaf(new or());

        t.set_right_son(new and());
        t.get_right().set_left_son_as_leaf(new or());
        t.get_right().set_right_son_as_leaf(new or());  

        consumer.join();
        t.calc_head_value();    //calc the head
        System.out.println("The result is: " + t.head.value);
        System.out.println();


    /******************************
     * compute with a single thread
    ********************************/

        System.out.println("compute with a single thread");
        int res = t.compute();
        System.out.println("The result is: " + res);


    /***********************************************
     * printing a arithmatic expression of the tree
    *************************************************/
        System.out.println();
        t.compute_with_print();






    }
}
```

Consumer

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Consumer extends Thread {

    Consumer() {

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        gate_node temp;

        // the threads pool parts
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

        try {
            while ((temp = main_class.queue.take()).father_c != null) {
                Runnable worker = new computingThread(temp);
                executor.execute(worker);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
        }

    }

}
```

computingThread

```
public class computingThread implements Runnable {
    gate_node head;

    int t_value;

    public computingThread(gate_node head) {
        this.head = head;
        this.t_value = -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        /* System.out.println("Start: "+this.hashCode()); */
        t_value = head.op.calc(head.left_v,head.right_v);

/*      System.out.println("thread: "+this.hashCode()+" is running ==> "+head.left_v+" "+head.op.toString()+" "+head.right_v+" = "+head.op.calc(head.left_v,head.right_v));
*/      head.value = this.t_value;

        // update the father

        if (head.isRightChild == true) { //update right fathers entire
            head.father_c.right_v = t_value;

            /*System.out.println("isRightChild");*/
        } else { //update left fathers entire
            head.father_c.left_v = t_value;
        }

        if ((head.father_c.right_v != -1) && (head.father_c.left_v != -1)){ //father is ready to compute-> to the queue!
            try {
                main_class.queue.put(head.father_c);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
    /*  try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
    /*  System.out.println("thread: "+this.hashCode()+" is done!");
*/      return;
    }
}
```

Here what I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to do a parllel comput that use multithreads to compute the finite value of the tree (each node gets two values, produce an outcome based on his opreator, pass it on the tree.. until the root is caculted). What I did is to set a queue of fixed number of spaces.

I insert the leafs to the queue as the tree is build. then I start a consumer that takes each leafs, caculate it, pass the result on the the right entrie of his father, and when both entreis are inserted into the father node, it also goes to the queue, and so on.. until the root is cacluted).

the only problem is that I cannot uses a queue that is smaller from the number of leafs in the tree, and I don't know why.

maybe becuase while I'm building the tree I'm inserting the leafs to the tree and if the queue is smaller then the leafs, I'm doing a: `main_class.queue.put(this.right_c);` when queue is already full, and that cause the progrem to wait until spaces on the queue will be freed which doesnt happen (cause I'm didn't start the threads yet).

Does anyone have any solution to that?

and another question? is that consider a parrlel computation? meaning if I set a queue with size 2, does that mean the I will do all the computation with only two threads (because I want to set is like the number of core CPU of a certain computer).

Thanks and sorry for my bad spelling.

Comment: Your code is not easy to read. So just 1st fast scan, there is only one thread beside main thread. It is not real parallel programing so processing runs in serial. I suppose that it cause your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you modelled it in a more complicated way than it was needed. I would not base my modelling on a tree. An electric circuit, is not always a tree. You could have more than one nodes acting as the circuits outputs, right?

I would base my modelling on the gate node. I would have a `Gate` class with two inputs and one output. Inputs and outputs, would be of type `GateValue`. Output would be calculated using a different way if the gate is an `and` or an `or` gate.

Then I would combine them building my circuit, like this:

```
gate1.Input1 = gate2.Output
gate1.Input2 = gate3.Output
```

etc.

Then, I would calculate the value of the last gate (output of the whole circuit) which would cause other gates to calculate their values. This way, you would not need a "parallel" calculation mechanism. As soon as you have no feedback loops in your circuit, this would work fine.

Hope I helped!